# Partial $x$-derivatives of $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if }(x,y)\neq (0,0), \\
0, & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}$$ Prove that $(D_1f)(x,y)$ at any point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I tried to solve it by the following way:

**1)** If $(x,y)=(0,0)$ then $$(D_1f)(0,0):=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(t,0)}{t}.$$ But here is I have some problem. What form has $f(t,0)$ above? I guess that $f(t,0)=\dfrac{0\cdot t}{0^2+t^2}=0$. Can here $t$ be equal $0$ since we would have $\dfrac{f(0,0)}{0}$?

**2)** Let $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ then $$(D_1f)(x,y)=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+t,y)-f(x,y)}{t}=\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+t,y)-\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}}{t}.$$ What form $f(x+t,y)$ has here? Can anyone explain it detailed?

I would be very thankful to any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking a limit $\lim_{t \to 0}$, then $t$ is not zero inside the limit.

If $(x,y) = 0$, then (with $t \neq 0$) $f(t,0) = 0$.

If $(x,y) \neq 0$, then (as long as $(x+t,y) \neq 0$, which can only occur for one non zero value of $t$) $f(x+t,y) = {(x+t)y \over (x+t)^2+y^2 }$.

---

It is clear that $f$ is smooth for any $(x,y) \neq 0$. This is because multiplication, addition and division (with non zero divisor, of course) is smooth.

In particular, ${\partial f(x,0) \over \partial x} = {y (y^2-x^2) \over (x^2+y^2)^2 }$.

Since $f(x,0) = 0$ for all $x$, it is clear that ${\partial f(x,0) \over \partial x} = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry but I guess that it's not answer to my question. I am asking not this.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Thank you for attention. I wrote my question above. I am asking what for $f(x+t,y)$ has in last expression.

Comment: You can read my question above in post. Unfortubately your answer is nice but it has no realtion with question :(

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking for someone to substitute $x+t$ and $y$ into the expression for $f(x,t) $ above?

Comment: Not! But $f(x,y)$ has two forms if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. I hope that you understood my question.

Comment: See the note I added to the top of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35559/discussion-between-raheem-najib-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Can we continue our conversation in chat?

Comment: Hello! I solved this problem in $\varepsilon-\delta$ language. Can you check my solution?

Comment: I don't see your solution anyways?

Comment: I meant anywhere.